# Adding local repository to a folder within a github repository

Tags: reactjs, git, github

**Background**
Im currently making lots of react apps. In order to have them all within a single repository so that they dont mix with Python and other projects, I want to put all projects into a single Github Repository.

[image]

In that Repository, I have folders such as "stock-tracker" and I want to push my repository to that file using Git Bash.

If I use `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/leonkuessner/React/stock-tracker.git`, and then `git push origin main`, I get the error:

`remote: Not Found fatal: repository 'https://github.com/leonkuessner/React/stock-tracker.git/' not found`

[image]

**Question**
How do I add a local repository to a folder within a Github repository

Im still very new to both Github ad Git, so if I explained this inadequately, please let me know in the comments and I will try to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to clone the repo
2. in this repo add remote to your local folder you want to insert to the repo
3. pull from this remote to your origin branch with --allow-unrelated-histories flag

> git remote add another-source ../../some/source

> git pull another-source master --allow-unrelated-histories